# Using col-sm & col-xs inside my razor view

Tags: html, css, razor

I have the following code inside a web template that i am using :-

```
</div>
<div class="row panel">
<div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
@Html.Action("Menu", "Nav")
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
@RenderBody()
</div>
</div>
```

but now i got confused on how the two divs will display in a full screen (large screen), as i understand the markup as follow:-

- the Menu will be hidden on X-small screens and occupy 3 columns on small size,, but what about large screens ?
- the RenderBoy will occupy 12 in x-small screens and 8 in small but what about large screens ?

Can anyone advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large screens always occupy the largest col size you provided. E.g.:

This will be 12 columns wide on **all** screen sizes

```
class="col-xs-12"
```

This will be 6 columns wide on **all** screen sizes **larger than** XS

```
class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"
```

This will be 4 columns wide on **all** screen sizes **larger than** MD

```
class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"
```

For the hidden tags the scenario is a little bit different. The content will exclusively be hidden on the sizes you provided. So `hidden-xs` is only hidden on XS screens (see also: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap's grid system works based on `min-width` attribute. it means for example `col-sm-8` is something like this:

```
.col-sm-8 {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
}
```

so, when you decorate an html element with `class="col-sm-8"`, these would happen:

- the default width is 100% (small devices below 768px of screen width)
- when you are in a screen with minimum width of 768px, the second rule will be applied. so the element gets a 66.66666667% of width. this part means, when you are in a md device (992px of width) or a lg device (1200px width), if the element hasn't another css rule for those devices, it will use the value which `.col-sm-8` had provided for the element (since 992 and 1200 both are greater than 768. aren't they? and we order the css for min-width of 768. so everything greater than that can use that rule).

my English is too bad.so please let me know if I couldn't explain clearly.